# How does java EE6 JSF Presentation and Logic layers interwork?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

Can anyone tell me how does a Java method get called by a JSF component? Is it the same as calling a Javascript function with a Managed Bean serving as my "JSON"/Model?

Comment: This is a pretty broad question and any self contained answer would possibly result in another new questions about the answer because you might be lacking some basic knowledge. Are you familiar with how HTTP and webapps in general works? Are you familiar with basic JSP/Servlet? Have you ever been through a decent JSF book/tutorial? If not, please do so. If so, which one?

Comment: Yes Apress Beginning Java EE6. Yes I know how a servlet works, I would like to know how function calling works since it's just annotated xhtml code, what happens to the XHTML code to make it runnable?

Comment: The `FacesServlet` controls this all. This question is definitely way too broad. Please spend some weeks learning/practicing/exercising/debugging JSF first. Not everyone is going to write book-worthy material as an answer on such an overly broad question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Apart from finding a serious misrepresentation of C monsters' and their habitation present in the wrong social public area with all its Asperger disorder)
Were you talking about ...
net.sf.json.util.JSONBuilder; and converting a bean to JSON
GSON library and API made by google

Java methods are called inside JSF pages by standard JSP/JSF page language syntax called "EL" "Expression Language".
JSF is a particular specialist "Java server framework", its syntax is quite similar to the JSP type of EL but the two have a small difference int their initial notation symbol.
In jsp it starts with "$" in JSF it start with "#".
If you are using a Java EE server then it would be the same.

Comment: >In jsp it starts with "$" in JSF it start with "#". - This is not correct. The first one is immediate EL, the second one is deferred EL. Since EL 2.1, which is common to both JSP and JSF, both variants are supported by JSF and JSF.